# How to get Branch Name from Tag

Tags: git

I have copied the repository from remote GitHub and now going into that git repository in local machine where repository downloaded.

below am issuing command to fetch the branch name, but its not working

```
$ git branch --contains v0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

From [git man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git.1.html):

> `--contains [<commit>]`
>
> Only list branches which contain the specified commit (HEAD if not specified). Implies `--list`.

and

> With `--contains`, shows only the branches that contain the named commit (in other words, t**he branches whose tip commits are descendants of the named commit**).

Just use

```
git branch
```

which should show all the local branches of your repo. The starred branch is your current branch.

If you want to retrieve only the name of the branch you are on, you can do:

```
git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Comment: `git branch --show-current` would be safer as your `grep` may find branches with `*` in their names. However, this does not get the branch name associated with a particular tag, which was what was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

`git branch` without `-a` only shows local branches.

You probably want `git branch -a --contains v0.3` to see all branches from github that contain the given tag. But this may be less helpful than you think - it will list the branch the tag was originally made on as well as any branches spawned off that since the tag.

Comment: Thanks i also explored with -a option and it worked .. as the tag is unique for me its working